# How to read ServletOutputStream

Tags: servlets

In my web application, I have two servlets as Servlet A and Servlet B. There is call to Servlet A from browser. Servlet A invokes Servlet B using RequestDispatcher calling include() method.

Servlet B writes some bytes on ServletOutputStream.

Now to the next line of include() method I want to read bytes wrote by Servlet B. How I can?

Abstract of code is as bellow.

```
public class A extends HttpServlet {
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/B");
     rd.include(request, response);

    // Now here i want to read bytes of ServletOutputStream for further processing
    // How do I?

   }
}
```

Again I certainly cannot modify code of servlet B. It is predefined. Secondly it is sure that servlet B writes bytes on ServletOutputStream.

Any help is really apprreciated.

Comment: `rd.include(request, response)` will not cause Servlet `B` to write out it's response. It will only _include_ Servlet `B`'s response in Servlet `A`'s. Is committing Servlet `A`s response and then reading a possibility for you?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html). Have a look for more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330288/writers-and-outputstreams-in-java-ee-applications-and-filters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701681/how-can-i-read-an-httpservletreponses-output-stream)

Comment: Thank you Kris, I went through HttpServletResponseWrapper and resolved my issue in conjunction with ServletFilter :)